# connecting midi with lightning cable

Tags: ios, midi, coremidi

i am trying to connect my iOS app that is a midi controller to mac with lightning cable.
i wrote the app with core midi and the connection is bonjour and its working, but i have latency ,according to apple with wifi, we will get 20ms latency.but when i test the app in Xcode and the cable is connected i have no latency, but if i run the app even with cable without Xcode, i get latency, do anyone know why?

now i want to connect with cable, since apple releases new future with audio/midi setup, that make possible to connect iPhone with cable and its possible to send midi out or in or send audio in or out, if we enable the iPhone ,we suppose to get connection, but in my case i have full functioning app that work with wifi but  as i connect it with audio/midi setup its not going to show the midi but if i do connect with wifi is going to work,
my question is ,how can i connect the midi with cable?, do i need some code? even if i use audio/midi future ? do i need some api to work with audio/midi future ? you can get connection with core midi network connection throw ip address or NetService /bonjour ,is there away to get connection with cable?

if you connect your iPhone to mac and open the audio/midi you can see the iPhone icon on the left side ,if you enable that you are in connection ,its going to tell you that its possible to send midi and so on.
please i need some help 
thank you all for taking your time

Answer (score 0):

if you want to connect the iPhone as a midi controller to your mac with cable, with the new inter-device audio :
you need to make sure your app works with MIDI, in other word, implementing the core midi , midi services, configuring the source and destination .
it should work just fine if you have iOS 11 and later and on mac side the el capital and later .